# cookie set in respose header but not in request

Tags: node.js, vue.js, express, cookies

i have server for deploy my backend project with url http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:6868
and try to access with frontend from localhostL:8080 but had problem with cookies that i set from backend for frontend. backend using express frontend using vue.js
here how i do that
in backend app.js

```
const startServer = async () => {
  logger.debug("startServer() was called, starting server");

  const app = express();

  app.use(cors({
    origin: true,
    credentials: true
    // origin: '*'
  }));
  app.use(cookieParser());
  app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Content-Type', "application/json");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', process.env.ALLOW_CROSS);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Set-Cookie, Accept");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    next();
});
```

.....
...

and for set cookies

```
   res.cookie("cookiebengkel", { "TOKEN": AccToken, "REFTOKEN": RefToken, uid: cook.uid, level: cook.level }, {
                  maxAge: 3600 * 12000, // 24 hours
                  httpOnly: false, // http only, prevents JavaScript cookie access           
                    secure: true, // cookie must be sent over https / ssl
                    domain: "localhost",
                  sameSite: "none",
                  path:"/"
                    
                    
                  });
```

and in frontend side i set api fetch like this

```
const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_ROOT_API,
    mode: "cors",
    withCredentials: true,
    credentials: 'include',
    headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:6868"

        

    },
}, {
```

**general**
the result that i got from browser like this
Request URL: http://Xxx.xxx.Xxx.xxx:6868/api/login
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: Xxx.xxx.Xxx.xxx:6868
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

**Response Headers**
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Set-Cookie, Accept
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,PUT,POST,DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 376
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Wed, 14 Jun 2023 17:37:06 GMT
ETag: W/"178-wKrmghaElVOrWWrVvk3QjWvFqYc"
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
Set-Cookie: cookiebengkel=j%3A%7B%22TOKEN%22%3A%22eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOiIxIiwidXNlcm5hbWUiOiIxIiwiaWF0IjoxNjg2NzY0MjI2LCJleHAiOjE2ODY3NjQzNDZ9.aRzEecNosu7f0jb2PA95U99qtDOD7zddvdeX-6s3Tsw%22%2C%22REFTOKEN%22%3A%22eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6IjEiLCJpYXQiOjE2ODY3NjQyMjYsImV4cCI6MTY4Njc2NzgyNn0.1g-WBLBLccNuZAhOAl3DO5jrvl1sNuOZXYD4uwlRHus%22%2C%22uid%22%3A%221%22%2C%22level%22%3A%22A%22%7D; Max-Age=43200; Domain=.localhost:8080; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 15 Jun 2023 05:37:06 GMT; Secure; SameSite=None
Vary: Origin
X-Powered-By: Express

**Request Headers**
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: id-ID,id;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://Xxx.xxx.Xxx.xxx:6868
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 31
Content-Type: application/json
Host: 202.157.186.101:6868
Origin: http://localhost:8080
Referer: http://localhost:8080/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36

the problem is request header not contain cookie that i set. so every time i read cookie that i set before cant be read